Implementing recursive type inference for strongly typed tuples
I have a type MyType that looks as so
type MyType<V> {
  value: V
}

I'm trying to implement a function that takes in a tuple of various MyType objects, and returns the values.
Desired behaviour:
const obj1 = {value:1}
const obj2 = {value: "hello"}
const obj3 = {value: new Date()}

const values = getValues(obj1, obj2, obj3)
// Need typescript to infer that values is of type [number, string, Date]

My attempt (I get an error when I try to return an empty list in the recursive function call):
type Infer<T> = T extends MyType<infer V> ? V : never;

type InferRecursive<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [] ?
    [] : T extends [infer U, ...infer URem] ?
    [Infer<U>, ...InferRecursive<URem>]
    : never;

function getValue<T extends MyType<any>>(obj: T): Infer<T> {
    return obj.value;
}

function getValues<T extends MyType<any>[]>(...objs: T): InferRecursive<T> {
    if (objs.length === 0) {
        // *ERROR HERE* --> [] cannot be assigned to InferRecursive<T>
        return [];
    }
    const [next, ...rest] = objs;
    return [
        getValue(next), ...getValues(...rest)
    ]
}

Desired behaviour:
const obj1 = {value:1}
const obj2 = {value: "hello"}
const obj3 = {value: new Date()}

const values = getValues(obj1, obj2, obj3)
// Need typescript to infer that values is of type [number, string, Date]

My attempt (I get an error when I try to return an empty list in the recursive function call):
type Infer<T> = T extends MyType<infer V> ? V : never;

type InferRecursive<T extends any[]> =
    T extends [] ?
    [] : T extends [infer U, ...infer URem] ?
    [Infer<U>, ...InferRecursive<URem>]
    : never;

function getValue<T extends MyType<any>>(obj: T): Infer<T> {
    return obj.value;
}

function getValues<T extends MyType<any>[]>(...objs: T): InferRecursive<T> {
    if (objs.length === 0) {
        // *ERROR HERE* --> [] cannot be assigned to InferRecursive<T>
        return [];
    }
    const [next, ...rest] = objs;
    return [
        getValue(next), ...getValues(...rest)
    ]
}


Is there a reason it needs to be a recursive function?  The same solution can be created with simpler types and methods.
type Val<T> = {
  value: T;
};

type TupleValues<T extends Val<any>[]> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key]["value"];
};

 function myFunc<T extends Val<any>[]>(...args: T){
   return args.map(x => x.value) as TupleValues<T>
 };

https://tsplay.dev/NdbDkW

The TypeScript error you're encountering occurs because the TypeScript compiler cannot reconcile the type of the empty array ([]) with the expected return type InferRecursive<T>. Since T in your function can be any tuple type of MyType<any>[], when you specify [], TypeScript does not automatically infer it to be compatible with every possible tuple structure T might represent.
One way to resolve this is by explicitly casting the empty array to the appropriate type. Here's a modified version of your getValues function that should work:
type MyType<V> = {
  value: V;
}

type Infer<T> = T extends MyType<infer V> ? V : never;

type InferRecursive<T extends any[]> = 
  T extends [] ? [] :
  T extends [infer U, ...infer URem] ? [Infer<U>, ...InferRecursive<URem>] : 
  never;

function getValue<T extends MyType<any>>(obj: T): Infer<T> {
    return obj.value;
}

function getValues<T extends MyType<any>[]>(...objs: T): InferRecursive<T> {
    if (objs.length === 0) {
        // Explicitly cast the empty array to the expected return type
        return [] as InferRecursive<T>;
    }
    const [next, ...rest] = objs;
    return [
        getValue(next),
        ...getValues(...rest)
    ] as InferRecursive<T>;
}

This function explicitly casts the empty array [] to InferRecursive<T> to ensure type safety and compatibility, allowing TypeScript to infer the correct types for tuples with varying structures of MyType<any>
